# Implement GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener properly on custom view

Tags: android

I have a `CustomAutoCompleteTextView` and I want to be able to call  `showDropDown();` when the user `double-tap` on it.

As the title says `implements GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener` sounds like a good solution, but once added the mandatory methods to my custom view I have no idea on **how to set the whole thing up**

These are the methods to implement:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
```

**I want to archive something like this:**

```
@Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            showDropDown();//AutoCompleteTextView's this line is enough but the event is never triggered
            return super.doYourThing();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a better way than `implements GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener` to archive this, notice that this solution is for **implement double tap inside a custom view** and **all of its instances**

```
boolean firstTouch = false;
    long time;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == event.ACTION_DOWN){
            if(firstTouch && (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) <= 300) {
                firstTouch = false;
                showDropDown();//In my case I want to showDropDown() change this line for whatever you want to do
            } else {
                firstTouch = true;
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
                //return false;Use this if you dont want to call default onTouchEvent()
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
         //return false;Use this if you dont want to call default onTouchEvent()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1) create a new `GestureDetector()`

```
detector = new GestureDetector(this,new OnGestureListener() {

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    showDropDown()
    return true;
}
```

2) Append your `CustomAutoCompleteTextView` with a `OnTouchListener`

```
txt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        detector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Like this still not triggering

Comment: I guess yes but I can just guess since you are not sharing a code snipped which shows where and how you add/create your TextView

Comment: I'm sure this will work but it has a problem for me, sorry for not specifying, i have several CustomAutoCompleteTextView and i want all of them to do the same so this way will be a lot of work. What I wan is implement the double tap function in the custom class that extends AutoCompleteTextView. And i just found a way! Sharing in a min. PD:Ty for your time mate!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked well for me:

tapDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener());

```
tapDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(new GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e){
              //Notified when a single-tap occurs.
              Log.w("Debug","Single tap event occurred in view with ID: "+ getId());
              return true;
            }
    
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
              Log.w("Debug","Double tap event occurred in view with ID: "+ getId());
              return true;
            }
    
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e)  {
              //Notified when an event within a double-tap gesture occurs, including the down, move, and up events.
              return true;
            }
          });
```

As mentioned in the previous solution:

```
txt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        tapDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
});
```